# Hyper-V - Default Switch & DHCP Server

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I want to create a virtual test environment (in Hyper-V [I know, some may say a bad choice but reality calls for it]) to play with things like Domain/DC, DHCP, etc.

Thus far I know that the "Default" Switch of Hyper-V will provide a guest with a 172.xxx.xxx.xxx IP address and also allow the guest to access the internet via the host. I guess that what you call a network bridge and I'd assume it may behave the same on KVM, or even Container Networking like LXD.

The question I have is: would a DHCP server running inside a VM with a bridged Network Adapter (aka the Default Switch) conflict with other clients (in terms of assigning IP addresses to them) on the local network of the Hyper-V host, or only affect clients of the same internal virtual Network?

Comment: As the description says on the Default Switch properties, it is _not_ a bridge but NAT.

Comment: tks! 1.) what is the difference NAT/Bridge? 2.) how about the nature of my question (no matter the default is a bridge or NAT)?

Comment: Bridge is L2. It is what switches do between their ports. NAT is L3, a router function. It is what your home-router does to translate your internal 192.168.x.x. address range to the Internet address provided by your ISP.

Comment: You cannot configure a DHCP server on the guest's default switch's vLAN, as the sole purpose of the default adapter is to provide internet access to the Hyper-V guest, with the Hyper-V host's default adapter serving as the DHCP server _(you can't have two DHCP server's on the same IP subnet without issue)_. You can add an external or internal adapter for that, however if you want it to serve an address to the Windows hosts' adapter, you'll need to install OpenVPN's TAP adapter to use as a vLAN, as Windows' IP stack will never support vLANs.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual switch is a standalone LAN that is NATTED to the outside world by a virtual router that is also part of Hyper-V. It is NOT bridged.

Hyper-V also provides DHCP to this LAN. That will obviously conflict with your own DHCP server on the virtual LAN. It will not affect other virtual LANs unless you explicitly configure the vritual router to do DHCP relay (no idea if that is even possible in Hyper-V).

In order to be able to safely play with your own DHCP in the virtual environment you need to configure Hyper-V not the do DHCP for that virtual LAN. (I'm no Hyper-V expert. I'm a VMWare guy. I don't know if Hyper-V can be configured such, but any decent virtualization product should be able to do that.)

Comment: the HyperV "internal" switch. Does that I believe. And I am aware of the fact that I can do that. My question here was not less about "how to create an isolated network in HyperV", but more about the nature of the "Default Switch". All ini All the comments have clarified on that quite a bit already

Comment: Regarding questions: AFAIK, the Default Switch & it's software components aren't able to be customized, as it's sole purpose is to provide WAN access to guest VMs _(implemented a few years ago to make this process simpler & more efficient, eliminating dependencies on any one physical adapter w/ WAN access)_; As to the other, it depends on whether vLAN adapters need to be used on Windows _(host or Windows guest)_ as the Windows IP stack will never support vLANs - the workaround is to use OpenVPN's TAP adapter to install a 2nd TAP adapter, setting property _Media Status_ to _Always Connected_